# bash: What EXACTLY does `"${array[@]}"` do?

Tags: bash, sh

Let's say I have a script `echoargs`

```
$ echo $#
$ echo $*
```

I can either put quotes around an array expansion and get this behavior:

```
$ arr=("a b" "c d" "e f")
$ echoargs "${arr[@]}"
3
a b c d e f
```

Or I can not put quotes and get this behavior:

```
$ echoargs ${arr[@]}
6
a b c d e f
```

And then this chunk of code:

```
$ for i in "q ${arr[@]} q"; do echo $i; done
q a b
c d
e f q
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays

Comment: Without double quotes , bash will perform word splitting according to IFS value (typical is newline, tab, space). So without double quotes "a b" is recognized as two different words = "a" and "b". This bash word splitting feature does not happening when you are using double quotes.

Answer (score 2):

There's really nothing all that magical happening, it's just quoting.

`for i in "q ${arr[@]} q"` 
is the same as 
`for i in "q ""${arr[@]}"" q"` which is the same as `for i in "q ""a b" "c d" "e f"" q"` which is the same as `for i in "q a b" "c d" "e f q"`

`echoargs ${arr[@]}` is the same as `echoargs a b c d e f`

`echoargs "${arr[@]}"` is the same as `echoargs "a b" "c d" "e f"`

Answer (score 1):

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Arrays:

> Any element of an array may be referenced using `${name[subscript]}`. The braces are required to avoid conflicts with the shell’s filename expansion operators. If the *subscript* is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the word expands to all members of the array *name*. These subscripts differ only when the word appears within double quotes. **If the word is double-quoted,** `${name[*]}` expands to a single word with the value of each array member separated by the first character of the `IFS` variable, and **`${name[@]}` expands each element of *name* to a separate word.** When there are no array members, `${name[@]}` expands to nothing. **If the double-quoted expansion occurs within a word, the expansion of the first parameter is joined with the beginning part of the original word, and the expansion of the last parameter is joined with the last part of the original word.** This is analogous to the expansion of the special parameters ‘@’ and ‘*’.

(Emphasis mine.)

Answer (score 0):

Use a different incarnation of `echoargs`:

```
echoargs() { echo $#; printf '[%s]\n' "$@"; }
arr=("a" "b  c" "  d  e  f  " " multiple
    lines too")
echoargs ${arr[@]}
echoargs "${arr[@]}"
echoargs ${arr[*]}
echoargs "${arr[*]}"
```

When I run that, I get the output:

```
$ echoargs() { echo $#; printf '[%s]\n' "$@"; }
$ arr=("a" "b  c" "  d  e  f  " " multiple
>         lines too")
$ echoargs ${arr[@]}
9
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
[f]
[multiple]
[lines]
[too]
$ echoargs "${arr[@]}"
4
[a]
[b  c]
[  d  e  f  ]
[ multiple
        lines too]
$ echoargs ${arr[*]}
9
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
[e]
[f]
[multiple]
[lines]
[too]
$ echoargs "${arr[*]}"
1
[a b  c   d  e  f    multiple
        lines too]
$
```

Basically, the `"${arr[@]}"` form preserves the internal spacing of the elements of the array.  Both the unquoted forms lose all the internal spacing information and split the array elements at sequences of one-or-more spaces.  The `"${arr[*]}"` notation preserves internal spacing, but combines all the elements to make a single string, with a space between value.

You use the one that suits your needs, but usually the `"${arr[@]}"` notation is the correct one to use.